# Is there a way to make Github un-approve a pull request if a new commit is pushed to the branch?

Tags: github

Using the new pull request approval process in Github, if I approve a PR but then a dev pushes a new commit to that branch I'd want the PR to go back to the state it is in to start with (i.e. not approved).

At the moment it stays green but in reality there is code that hasn't been reviewed in the branch.

Comment: You might be able to do this using the GitHub API: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
Under your repository name, click **Settings**.
In the left menu, click **Branches**.
Select the branch you want to restrict using the drop-down menu.

Select **Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed**.

[image]

This dismisses a pull request approval review when a code-modifying commit is pushed to the branch.

Click Save changes.

Ref: https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-required-reviews-for-pull-requests/

Comment: Follow-up question: what exactly is a "code-modifying commit"? Is there some way to configure certain config files to be "ignored" when deciding whether to dismiss a review as stale?

Comment: @JeffGran None that I know of. It was basically about the merge commits which happen when you click "Update branch". It does not dismiss reviews as long as you have no severe conflicts.

Comment: Can dismiss the PR approval for the new commit changes, but keep it when merging from master branch?

Comment: Does this also invalidate approval if the branch is rebased?

Comment: This is not available in private repos for free accounts.

Comment: Is there a way to do this but only when a PR is moved from draft PR to "Ready to Review" (normal PR)?

Answer (score 36):

It's not clear from your question if you need this automatically done, or if a manual process is okay too.

In my case a manual solution was fine.  We'll just rely on developers to use their judgment on whether a PR should be unapproved.

To manually unapprove a PR, you can go to the comments section where the approval is, and click "show all reviewers".  Then choose Dismiss for each approved review.

Comment: Unfortunately it would need to be automatic but thanks for the input! You thought me something  :)