# How could I remove my approval from a pull request on github?

Tags: github, pull

I approved a pull request of a random repository I do not have write access too. How can I remove or delete that approval?

Answer (score 131):

## Dismiss review

You can "Dismiss review" in **the bottom section** of the PR.

1. expand approval(s)
2. click three dots
3. choose `Dismiss review`

(not present in the timeline - little bit confusing)

[image: 3 steps to dismiss review]

then it looks like (in the timeline)

[image: result after dismiss review]

Comment: GitHub interface is almost as convoluted as git cmd line. The influence is obvious :)

Comment: IMHO it should be in the timeline as well (not only hidden inside accordion at the bottom)

Comment: IDK why but this did not revert the `All checks have passed`, despite adding a request changes later.

Comment: `All checks have passed` is about pipeline... (build, lint, test etc.), why should approval have impact on that?

Comment: Can't see this option.

Comment: @ShimmyWeitzhandler, I've just conducted a test, and it's functioning flawlessly. All my screenshots remain unchanged.

Comment: I guess it's probably the repo owners custom settings

Answer (score 14):

For quick resolution,I suggest to **Dismiss the review** by stating the reason.

Note: It will be recorded in the history of events of the PR that you had approved & dismissed earlier.

Answer (score 7):

You might need to contact the repository owner.

From "[Is there a way to make Github un-approve a pull request if a new commit is pushed to the branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47553095/6309)", there is an option that would dismiss stale pull request approval when new commits are pushed.

But that is for the owner to activate.

Another option (still for the owner of the repository)

[Dismissing a pull request review](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/dismissing-a-pull-request-review)

Answer (score 7):

You can also re-request your own review (the refresh symbol next to your green tick)

Comment: that did not negate approval

Comment: Cool that also worked for a _Request for Changes_.