# How to prevent against merging two independntly valid pull requests, yet would cause a regression if they're both merged?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, pull-request

We run our tests against any open pull request (PR), so a PR shouldn't be merged if there is a failing test case.

We occasionally face the following scenario:

1. **PR #1**: All tests are passing. But it's introducing a change that would break our master branch if PR# 2 is merged.
2. **PR #2**: All tests are passing. But it will break our master branch if PR# 2 is merged.

Both PRs are passing the checks and nothing can stop them from being merged!

How can we prevent that? Is there a GitHub feature that could synchronously (one PR at a time) try to automatically rebase a PR before merging it?

Comment: Are you manually merging those PRs through GitHub UI? Do you have branch protection to force the PR to have the latest master code? For example, when you merge the PR 1, the PR 2 is forced to update with that code, and it will re-run the build again, and the merge will be blocked until the build succeeds. Here's more information: https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches#require-status-checks-before-merging

Comment: That should resolve it inshallah! We'll give it a try.

Comment: It should work. Let me know how it goes. Good luck! :)

Comment: It worked perfectly but there is one considerable drawback. Our PRs require approvals from code owners and that approval is lost when we rebase to pass the PR checks because we have to rebase and force push. I'll have to convince everyone that this is the best we can do but I'm wondering if there is another way to reduce that manual interaction and communication (to re-gather approvals again) before actually merging.

Comment: Do you want to re-request a review on a pull request after the rebase? I am not sure if github has a built-in option to do that automatically. However, you can create another workflow to automate that process. You can trigger the workflow only if it is a push on a PR AND if the review state is 'approved'. This [link](https://github.community/t/feature-request-trigger-action-on-pull-request-approved/18413/2) will give you an idea. And then you can use the [github API to re-request a review](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#request-reviewers-for-a-pull-request). What do you think?

Comment: It's not about re-requesting approval, it's about the approvals being lost when someone else merges a PR. We create numerous PRs and everyone is trying to get approvals for his PR. The solution you suggested, which is the best I found so far, means that approvers will keep getting requests to approve the same PR multiple times before the PR owner snipes a chance to merge his PR.

Comment: The approvals shouldn't be lost when someone merges a PR. At least, it doesn't happen with my PRs. Even if you commit new changes, the approval persists. Maybe did you select [Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505904/is-there-a-way-to-make-github-un-approve-a-pull-request-if-a-new-commit-is-pushe)?